# How to use uploading dropped and pasted images using CKeditor

Tags: image, upload, ckeditor

I want to implement following using fuelPHP.
http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.5.0-beta/image-upload.html

Then, I added all plugins and can upload the images to my directory.

However, I do know the format of the response for client side of CKEditor and so CKEditor is not able to locate file path.

Dose anyone know the format of its response?

I return the json object like following.

json_encode(array('responseText'=>'ok','uploaded'=>1,'fileName'=>"/assets/img/upload/d2ceb4f415e252199483ee96f5ba361d.png"),true);

Comment: I solve myself.

Answer (score 0):

The response should be like following
{
    "uploaded": 1,
    "fileName": "foo.jpg",
    "url": "/files/foo.jpg"
}